# How to monitor SignalR ConnectionState in Angular 11 after SignalR connection is established continously

Tags: signalr, angular11, asp.net-core-signalr

I am trying to find a way to monitor a SignalR connection continuously like say every minute or every 3 minutes.
Trying to find a way to check the connection state. Do I need to set up an observable that can be subscribed to. But then that would have to be in a Component or do I do that in  the app.Module or app.component ?
Is it connection.OnClose();

the Angular Code in my SignalR Service class is:

```
 Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalrService {
 connection: signalR.HubConnection;
  
 constructor() {
   this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
   .withUrl(environment.hubAddress)
   .build();
   this.connect();
 }
  
 public connect() {
   if (this.connection.state === signalR.HubConnectionState.Disconnected) {
     this.connection.start().catch(err => console.log(err));
   }
 }
  
 public getMessage(next) {
     this.connection.on('SendMessage', (message) => {
       next(message);
     });
 }
  
 public disconnect() {
   this.connection.stop();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by checking connection reconnecting(), reconnected() and onClose()events:

```
    constructor() {
   this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
   .withUrl(environment.hubAddress)
   .build();
   
    this.connection.reconnecting() => {}
this.connection.reconnected() => {}
    this.connection.onClose() => {}

    this.connect();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct syntax is like this:

```
this.connection.onreconnected(() => {
  console.log('connection reconnecting ...');
});

this.connection.onreconnected(() => {
  console.log('connection onreconnected .');
});

this.connection.onclose(() => {
  console.log('connection closed .');
});
```